# Running Multiple Monkey Runner (Python script)Program from a single script

Tags: android, python, android-emulator, python-3.x, monkeyrunner

For single program we use -->

```
./monkeyrunner Python_prog_name.py
```

Likewise i want to run 4 small programs... **How will i run those 4 programs from a single script ?**

Comment: You could integrate the code into one script...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming from your question that you're unfamiliar with the Unix shell....

If you want to run them one at a time, create and execute a script with the following contents:

```
./monkeyrunner Python_prog_name1.py 
./monkeyrunner Python_prog_name2.py 
./monkeyrunner Python_prog_name3.py 
./monkeyrunner Python_prog_name4.py
```

If you want to run them all at once, create and execute a script with the following contents:

```
./monkeyrunner Python_prog_name1.py &
./monkeyrunner Python_prog_name2.py &
./monkeyrunner Python_prog_name3.py &
./monkeyrunner Python_prog_name4.py &
```